# How to use this function with multiple parts of a php program

Tags: php

I'm new to writing functions that are shared between different parts of a program. I have this function type below that runs perfectly alone but I want to make it run with with different data sets so then I don't need to copy/duplicate the whole function. The way the function works is it grabs saved data that is in a database then it converts to the correct equal part then its easily displayed with something like echo. The two first lines in the function can't be in the function if its going to function with multiple parts but I don't know how to do that. And if you use global or move the $ parts outside the function the function does not function obviously. So I am stuck. If any questions, let me know.

```
function something() {
$data_in_database_one = get_option( 'config' );
$something = $data_in_database_one['data_in_database_one'];
if     ( ( $something ) ==   '0' ) : echo 'zero';
elseif ( ( $something ) ==   '1' ) : echo 'one';
elseif ( ( $something ) ==   '2' ) : echo 'two';
elseif ( ( $something ) ==   '3' ) : echo 'three';
elseif ( ( $something ) ==   '4' ) : echo 'four';
elseif ( ( $something ) ==   '5' ) : echo 'five';
else :
 echo '';
endif;
}
```

This part needs to not be in the function:

```
$data_in_database_one = get_option( 'config' );
$something = $data_in_database_one['data_in_database_one'];
```

Because there will be multiple data sections for example:

```
$data_in_database_two = get_option( 'config' );
$something = $data_in_database_two['data_in_database_two'];
```

and:

```
$data_in_database_three = get_option( 'config' );
$something = $data_in_database_three['data_in_database_three'];
```

and:

```
$data_in_database_four = get_option( 'config' );
$something = $data_in_database_four['data_in_database_four'];
```

and:

```
$data_in_database_five = get_option( 'config' );
$something = $data_in_database_five['data_in_database_five'];
```

As you see in the examples the names all change in all parts, the name changes in 3 titles in the 2 lined examples I show above.

So: I thought to write some "if" statements that do something like (not actual code only written so you understand me):

```
if $this is called then
use these lines
$data_in_database_one = get_option( 'config' );
$something = $data_in_database_one['data_in_database_one'];
elseif $this_two is called then
use these lines
$data_in_database_two = get_option( 'config' );
$something = $data_in_database_two['data_in_database_two'];
```

But I don't know how to write that. And I don't know how to connect that all to the original function something(). ???

Comment: Use function parameters?

Answer (score 0):

If `$data_in_database_one = get_option( 'config' );` is always the same and if it's just the key of `data_in_database_one` who change... Maybe you can try something like this ?

```
function something(string $data_key) {
    $config = get_option( 'config' );
    switch ($config[$data_key]) {
        case '0':
            echo 'zero';
            break;
        case '1':
            echo 'one';
            break;
        case '2':
            echo 'two';
            break;
        case '3':
            echo 'three';
            break;
        case '4':
            echo 'four';
            break;
        case '5':
            echo 'five';
            break;
        default:
            echo '';
            break;
    }
}
```

You can see i use switch case rather than many ifs

And after on your program you can do something like that :

```
something('data_in_database_one'); //Will echo 'one'
something('data_in_database_two'); //Will echo 'two'
```

With your example it can be:

```
if ($this) {
    something('data_in_database_one');
} else if ($this_two) {
    something('data_in_database_two');
}
```

I don't know if it was what you espect ?

Edit if i understand the problem and if the echo was not needed :

```
function something(string $data_key) {
 $config = get_option('config');
 return $config[$data_key];
}

//Now you can use :
$data_in_use_one = something('data_in_database_one');
$data_in_use_two = something('data_in_database_two');
```

Comment: Both the $data_in_database_one and they key data_in_database_one changes. So that is the difficult part. But you might be on to something with string $data_key within (). I'm new to all that so trying to figure it out. I will try your ideas.

Comment: It still seems in your example that $data_key would need to be different type of code because the names do change and can't be defined in the function. I don't know. Maybe there is another way. The names could have a partial name the same like the ending 2 characters or something.

Comment: In this second I'm reading something about: foreach($GLOBALS ... maybe something of that would work...

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want to do. 

If you just want to have something return the database to use see my edit on this post

Comment: Ok so I solved the idea by using your string $variable idea, but I used a different method by just putting my original function code in a separate file with require_once to that file. Then I call the function with the echo and  the 2 required variable lines, and that works fine. Maybe not the best?

Comment: Paste your code if you want an review